# How to trigger task after getting camelcontext?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel framework.I have inject below camelcontext bean(i.e with id camel) into CreationImpl and am able to access endpoints and routes from that camelcontext object. I want to know how to trigger the task. I don't know whether it is correct way? Please suggest.

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel">
        <camel:jmxAgent id="agent" createConnector="true" usePlatformMBeanServer="true" connectorPort="1516" registryPort="1515" />
        <camel:endpoint id="email" uri="${email}" />

        <camel:route errorHandlerRef="createErrorHandler" id="createRoute">
            <camel:from uri="direct:startReading"/>
            <camel:doTry>
                <camel:bean ref="creationProcessor" method="method1"/>
                <camel:bean ref="creationFilter" method="method2"/>
                <camel:bean ref="creatorFeedback" method="method3"/>
                <camel:bean ref="creatorFeedback" method="method4"/>
                <camel:doCatch>
                    <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
                    <camel:bean ref="creatorFeedback" method="method5"/>
                </camel:doCatch>
            </camel:doTry>
        </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>

public class CreationImpl{
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    public void migrate{
        //how to trigger the route after getting camelcontext object
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getCamelContext().stopRoute("cmpCreatorRoute");
getCamelContext().startRoute("cmpCreatorRoute");
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On the Camel website there is a getting started section. Its a good idea to read that and the links it provides, to get some more Camel knowledge.

For example there is a link where this example is covered step by step:
http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html

You can then find details how to "trigger a route"